# Bootstrap MODAL - how to open YouTube in mobile without the pop?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

MODAL by default activate in mobile the ordinary pop up windows, which interfear with how iOS\Android UX is working.

How\What should i added to the code so that in Mobile it will not use Modal but just open the youtube video?

10x for the help
Udi

```
<a href="javascript:changeVideo('e80BbX05D7Y')"><button class="main-btn">Watch</button></a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
     $("#iframeYoutube").attr("src","#");
  })
})

function changeVideo(vId){
   var iframe=document.getElementById("iframeYoutube");
   iframe.src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+vId+"? 
   modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0";

   $("#myModal").modal("show");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must detect mobile browser with js. You can do this with [mobile-detect.js](http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/).

If you update your code like this, it will works.

```
<a href="javascript:changeVideo('e80BbX05D7Y')"><button class="main-btn">Watch</button></a>

<script>

var mobileDetect = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
     $("#iframeYoutube").attr("src","#");
  })
})

function changeVideo(vId){
   var iframe=document.getElementById("iframeYoutube");
   iframe.src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+vId+"? 
   modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0";

if (mobileDetect.mobile()) {
    window.location = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + vId;
return;
  }

   $("#myModal").modal("show");
}
</script>
```